# Google Maps Api v3, marker load from XML, not show on map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a big problem with Google Maps Api and jQuery. 
I need get markers from XML file, and show on map.

This is page with map:
http://szymonnosal.pl/sandbox/bsk/

And my code:

I initialize map:

```js
var mapa;   // obiekt globalny
var dymek;  // okno z informacjami
var networks = []; 
var locations = [];

function mapaStart()  
{  
    var wspolrzedne = new google.maps.LatLng(50.0157021545812, 19.9094574787954);
    var opcjeMapy = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: wspolrzedne,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: true
    };
    mapa = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapka"), opcjeMapy);            
    dymek = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    loadNetworks();

    google.maps.event.addListener(mapa,'click',function(){
        resetLocations();
    }); 
}
```

In loadNetwork() I load marker from XML file, I using jQuery:

```js
function loadNetworks()
{
$.get('net.xml',function(xml){
    $(xml).find("network").each(function(){
        var lat         =   parseFloat($(this).find("lat").text());
        var lon         =   parseFloat($(this).find("lon").text());
        var icon_url    =   $(this).find("icon").text();
        var SSID        =   $(this).find("SSID").text();
        var BSSID       =   $(this).find("BSSID").text();
        var AuthMode    =   $(this).find("AuthMode").text();
        var Frequency   =   $(this).find("Frequency").text();
        //alert(lat+'  '+lon+'  '+icon_url+'  '+SSID+'  '+BSSID+'  '+AuthMode+'  '+Frequency);
        var marker      =   addNetwork(lat,lon,icon_url,SSID,BSSID,AuthMode,Frequency);  
        alert(marker.txt); // <- marker is correct object, because in alert pop-up is text from marker. 
    });
});
}
```

And in addNetwork I add marker on map.

```js
function addNetwork(lat,lon,icon_url,SSID,BSSID,AuthMode,Frequency)
{
    var size = new google.maps.Size(30,23);   
    var start_point = new google.maps.Point(0,0);   
    var start_hook = new google.maps.Point(15,12);   

    var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon_url, size, start_point, start_hook); 

    var marker  =   new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
            title: BSSID,
            icon: icon,
            map: mapa
        }
    );
    marker.txt = 'BSSID: '+BSSID+'<br/>SSID: '+SSID+'<br />AuthMode: '+AuthMode+'<br />Frequency: '+Frequency;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function()
    {
        dymek.setPosition(marker.getPosition());
        dymek.setContent(marker.txt);
        dymek.open(mapa);
    });

    return marker;
}
```

If i use other function to load XML, it's correct:

```js
function loadNetworks()
{
    jx.load('getNetwork.php', function(xml)
    {
        var markery = xml.getElementsByTagName("network");
        for(var i=0; i<markery.length; i++)
        {
            var lat         =   parseFloat(markery[i].attributes.getNamedItem("lat").nodeValue);
            var lon         =   parseFloat(markery[i].attributes.getNamedItem("lon").nodeValue);
            var ikona_url   =   markery[i].attributes.getNamedItem("ikona").nodeValue;
            var SSID        =   markery[i].attributes.getNamedItem("SSID").nodeValue;
            var BSSID       =   markery[i].attributes.getNamedItem("BSSID").nodeValue;
            var AuthMode    =   markery[i].attributes.getNamedItem("AuthMode").nodeValue;
            var Frequency   =   markery[i].attributes.getNamedItem("Frequency").nodeValue;
            var marker      =   addNetwork(lat,lon,ikona_url,SSID,BSSID,AuthMode,Frequency);
        }
        alert('Wczytano '+markery.length+' markerów z pliku networks.xml');
    },'xml','get');
}
```

jx is function from: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jx/

Do You have any idea, what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like the icon_url is not defined.  A test would be to change the marker definition to:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
             {
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
               title: BSSID,
               // icon: icon,
               map: mapa
             });
```

This is on the live site:

```
var icon_url = jQuery(this).find("icon").text();
```

Not this (which is your posted code):

```
var ikona_url = markery[i].attributes.getNamedItem("ikona").nodeValue;
```

Your xml uses "ikona", and is the content of the element not an attribute.

```
<networks>
  <network>
    <lat>50.0158556853</lat>
    <lon>19.9096229322</lon>
    <SSID>untitled</SSID>
    <BSSID>f0:7d:68:48:97:00</BSSID>
    <AuthMode>[WPA-PSK-TKIP+CCMP][WPA2-PSK-TKIP+CCMP][ESS]</AuthMode>
    <Frequency>2447</Frequency>
    <ikona>http://maps.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png"</ikona>
  </network>
</networks>
```

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. I had extra  char " in my code in "ikona". Small error, and big effect. Now is correct. :) Thanks You very much

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way you can convert XML to JSON as returned data?

If yes, then try vMap.

vMap is a lightning jQuery plugin with HTML 5 that makes Google Maps easy by sending a simple JSON Data Structure.

https://github.com/vhugogarcia/vMap

It helped me to solve a lot the markers problem with Google Maps, but also adds the feature for listing the locations if needed.

Feel free to modify it as your needs.